# Kendo numeric textbox change event without lost focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

Is it possible to configure the kendo numeric textbox that my bound view model will receive an update when i click on the spin or change the numbers with keys? At the moment, only if the numeric text box lose the focus my view model will receive the update event.

The kendo databinding option data-value-update ... has sadly no effect on numeric text boxes

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, but you might want to have a look at this: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/numerictextbox#events-change. ( Congrats on your hilarious username :) )

Comment: thx i saw this page before but i got new idea to do manually binding to my viewmodel if the spin event is fired:
spin: function() {
        var value = this.value();
        viewModel.set("MyViewModelProperty", value);
}
But now i have still the proplem if the user update the numeric text box with the keyboard that my view model only receive an update when the numeric updown lost his focus...

Answer (score 8):

I know it's kinda late but here is my solution:

```
var numericBox = $("#yournumericinput").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
.
.
.
numericBox.element.on("keyup", function (e) {
    var newValue = e.target.value;        
    numericBox.value(newValue);
    numericBox.trigger("change");
});
```

That way the `change` event gets triggered immediately after the user has entered a new value, without having to wait for the `blur` event. Data validation checks are removed for brevity, but I advise you perform those as well.

And you could also bind the `spin` listener to trigger the `change` event.

```
numericBox.bind("spin", function (e) {
     this.trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, worked for me, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below code. It works for me.

ViewModel

```
viewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
        console.log("property Changed on spin ");
    });
```

Razor code

```
 <input id="tbSlideDuration" data-role="numerictextbox"
                             data-format="#"
                             data-min="1"
                             data-max="100"
                             data-bind="value:slideDuration, events: {spin:change}" />
```

this will call the change event under the hood :)